# Application of MVT to prove limit

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ be a twice-differentiable real function of the real variable $x$ such that $f$, $f'$ and $f''$ are all $\ge 0 $ over the set of reals.

We assume that $f''$ is not the zero function.

1) prove that $f$ and $f'$ are increasing and that there exists a real $r$ such that $f'(r) > 0$ (done)

2) prove using the MVT on segment $[r,x]$ ($x>r$) that

$$\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} f'(x)=+\infty$$

I'm having trouble with this last question.

The MVT ensures the existence of a real $c_x$ such that

$$f'(x) = f'(r) + f''(c_x)(x-r)$$

How to be sure that $f''(c_x)$ is not zero ?

Thanks

Comment: If $f''$ is zero for large $R$ then this cannot be true, because after that $f'$ will be constant, right? Certainly $f$ will go to infinity, the same cannot be said of $f'$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOT TRUE.

Consider
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x\Big(\int_{-\infty}^t \mathrm{e}^{-s^2}\,ds\Big)\,dt
$$
Then $f'(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x \mathrm{e}^{-s^2}\,ds>0$ and $f''(x)=\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}>0$, for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

But 
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-s^2}\,ds=\sqrt{\pi}.
$$

Comment: +1. Nice example.!